# Calculate this limit : $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[4]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[6]{x}}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Calculate this limit :

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[4]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[6]{x}}$$

It is not allowed to use Hopital rule or taylor
I tried to factorize but i didn't find any result

Comment: Let $x=y^{12}$. This is analogous to limits of rational functions, what can you say about the terms with the biggest exponents?

Comment: "I tried to factorize but i didn't find any result" Hmmm, let us factorize indeed: $$\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[4]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[6]{x}}=\sqrt[6]{x}\frac{1+\frac1{\sqrt[4]{x}}}{1+\frac1{\sqrt[6]{x}}}$$

Answer (score 4):

Just take $x = y^{12}$. Then, the limit changes to:
$$
\lim _{y \to +\infty} \frac{y^6 +y^3}{y^4 + y^2} = \lim _{y \to +\infty} \frac{y^6 }{y^4 + y^2} + \lim _{y \to +\infty} \frac{y^3}{y^4 + y^2}
$$

(Edit, thanks to @egreg)It is easily observe the following:
$$
\frac{y^6 +y^3}{y^4 + y^2} = y^2 \left( \frac{1 + \frac 1{y^3}}{1 + \frac 1{y^2}}\right)
$$

and while the limit of the bracketed portion is $1$, $y^2$ is unbounded, hence we have that the whole term is unbounded.

Comment: Why not simply observe that you get $y^2\frac{1+\frac{1}{y^3}}{1+\frac{1}{y^2}}$ without splitting the fraction?

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the point out I suppose my method was too elaborate. Do you think I should edit my answer?

Comment: I'd definitely do like I suggested: after all the fraction goes to $1$, so you're using the same argument in an easier way.

Comment: @egreg Okay, I will add your approach alternately to mine. In fact, yours gets precedence. I like splitting the terms, because when we would explain these limits to our friends in fifth class, we would always expand and evaluate term by term to make things clearer.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:  Numerator is bigger than denominator